# ng2-date-picker - After typing date in datepicker input we can see that date in calendar, but after selecting it from calendar it deletes from input

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker

After typing date in datepicker input we can see that date in calendar, but after we type that date and it shows in calendar, we select it from calendar but it deletes from input. I guess it is problem with same dates, so if you type some date and then select that same date from calendar it somehow repeal. Someone knows how to solve this problem? We need this date even if it is the same one from typing.

```
file.html
<dp-date-picker
                    id="search_dateFrom"
                    class="dp-date-picker"
                    theme="dp-material"
                    mode="day"
                    placeholder="DD.MM.GGGG."
                    [config]="this.config"
                    [(ngModel)]="datesArray['dateFrom']"
                    (onSelect)="checkValue($event)"
                    (ngModelChange)="onChangeSearch2($event)"
                  >
                  </dp-date-picker>

file.ts

onChangeSearch2(event)
  {
    console.log('event',event);
  }

checkValue(event){
    if (event.type == 'selection')
      if(event.date._i)
      {
        this.datesArray['dateFrom']=event.date._i;
      }

  }
```

[image: after typing]

Comment: Could you add your code as well?

Comment: @AldinBradaric added this test version, don't have yet the real one

Comment: Might be worthwhile to look at `event.date._i`. And then compare it to what value `datesArray['dateFrom']` has when you initially type in the date.

Comment: @AldinBradaric I tried something like that but didn't end successful.Same this problem is when you select for example today's date in calendar, it writes in input, and then you select again same date from calendar it deletes from input.

Comment: I took a look at the docs (ie https://vlio20.github.io/angular-datepicker/daytimePicker) and assuming you're using the simple `dayPicker` that seems to be the intended behavior. Edit: and reading further, there is a property called `unSelectOnClick` which does exactly what you want (ie prevent unselection).

Comment: @AldinBradaric really didn't know about this. Tnx :) it solved my problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might as well post a proper answer.

According to the [docs](https://github.com/vlio20/angular-datepicker) it seems to be the default behavior that dates can be both selected and unselected. Fortunately, there is a property called `unSelectOnClick` which if set to false, prevents the user from unselecting dates.